# Dynamically choose column to filter on

Tags: azure-data-explorer, ms-app-analytics

I'm trying to dynamically create a query and filter from a table not known at compile time (specifically, I want to filter on `id` if I'm querying the `requests` table, `operation_ParentId` otherwise). The following fails because `id` is not a column in the `exceptions` table:

```
let dataset = exceptions;
dataset
| where (itemType == "request" and id == "test") or (itemType != "request" and operation_ParentId == "test")
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using [`columnifexists()`](https://docs.loganalytics.io/docs/Language-Reference/Scalar-functions/columnifexists()):

```
let dataset = exceptions;
dataset
| where (itemType == "request" and columnifexists("id", operation_ParentId) == "test") or (itemType != "request" and operation_ParentId == "test")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ‘union’ the two tables:

```
let dataset = union exceptions, requests;
...
```

Comment: Thanks Assaf; this does work! However, I should have mentioned that I'm only querying one table at a time, but I don't know which one it will be at compile-time. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Then you can perhaps use ‘[where *](http://4pp1n51ght5.com/2017/12/20/cool-uses-for-searching-all-tables-searching-all-fields/) == ‘zzz’’ to always search on all the fields. It’s less performant, but should work.